# interchanging of limits : uniform convergence and limit at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Let $\{f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\}$ be a sequence of functions with uniform limit $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and let $\{c_{n}\}$ be a sequence defined by $$c_{n}:=\lim_{x\to\infty}f_{n}(x),$$ where the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f_{n}(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\{c_{n}\}$ is a convergent sequence.

The following are my two attempts:

(1) Since $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$|f_{m}(t)-f_{n}(t)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$ whenever $m,n\ge K$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $t_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ large enough so that $$|f_{n}(x)-c_{n}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$ whenever $x\ge t_{n}$.

So, for any $m,n\ge K$, choose $a=\max\{t_{m},t_{n}\}$, then $$|c_{m}-c_{n}|\le|c_{m}-f_{m}(a)|+|f_{m}(a)-f_{n}(a)|+|f_{n}(a)-c_{n}|<\varepsilon,$$ i.e., $\{c_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $\{c_{n}\}$ is a convergent sequence. $\square$

(2) Since $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$|f_{m}(x)-f_{n}(x)|<\varepsilon$$ whenever $m,n\ge N$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

So, if $m,n\ge N$, we have $$|c_{m}-c_{n}|=\left|\lim_{x\to\infty}f_{m}(x)-\lim_{x\to\infty}f_{n}(x)\right|=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left|f_{m}(x)-f_{n}(x)\right|\le\varepsilon.$$

The first proof seems to be no problem. However, the second proof doesn't seem rigorous.

Can anyone criticize my proofs? Give some advice. Thank you!

Comment: Are the functions all continuous?

Comment: @cmk No, without assuming continuity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that the statement is true at all,even if continuity is assumed.

Take the sequence $f_n=x+\frac{1}{n}$

It converges uniformly to $x$

But $c_n=+\infty,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ as $x \to +\infty$.

If each $f_n$ was bounded for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$ or more strongly,the sequence was uniformly bounded then your attempts are correct.

> If the limits are assumed to exist and be real numbers,then the first attempt is
>   is correct..Just instead of taking the maximum of $t_n,t_m$ you can put $t_m$ in $f_m$ and $t_n$ in $f_n.$
>
> Also the second is correct since $\lim_{x \to +\infty}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=\limsup_{x \to +\infty}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \leq \epsilon$

Comment: In this problem, the existence of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f_{n}(x)$ is assumed.

Comment: @Primavera..... You have to mention it then in your post,because it is not clear

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be sufficient $\{c_{n}\}$ is a real sequence.

Comment: @Primavera i edited though my answer..

Comment: Thank you for concerning. I've also edited the posting.

Comment: @MariosGretsas if we consider domain as complex plane and codomain as extended complex plane (which is complete metric space),then same result would be true ,am i right?